# What is the correct term of this part on a typeface

Tags: fonts, terminology

a quick question.
What is the correct term of this (see picture) on a font?

[image: Moderat font]

Comment: I feel like there are two different things that you've circled

Comment: Which specific part are you referring to, can you please elaborate a bit more. (I'm not really sure what you're talking about)

Comment: @ZachSaucier I think its **3** different things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Joint

- joint: gradual coming together of two strokes that meet to become one.

Could also be called the **apophyge** in some situations:

- apophyge: small curved part, usually ¼ circle, which connects the main stem with the terminals or serifs.

Also realize you've kind of circled the joint of a tail, a crossbar, and an bowl/stem.

In the case of p or t, it seems apophyge may be more appropriate. But the tail would be a joint.

> Ref: http://www.oert.org/en/typographic-anatomy/

Answer (score 2):

The spot on the p: That would be a taper

[image]

The spot on the t: That's a cupped stem

[image]

The spot on the a: would just be a closed-bowl stroke where it meets the stem.

Comment: I think taper is referring the stroke of the P's bowl, not the connection to the stem And the t isn't a cupped stem because in the question's sample, it's not a full "cup", it's a crossbar and a stem -- with a joint. But then you can spell pair, pare, pear.. many ways as well :)

Comment: @Scott hmm good point. Then it's a bracket not an apophyge no?

Comment: Hard to say because a bracket is generally on the stem/serif. Since what appears to be circled is the *not* the actual serif, but the stem/bowl connection... I think apophyge or joint *might* be more appropriate.. but I wouldn't really argue the point :)